# I want to give validation for mobile number in vb6

Tags: validation, vb6

I give validation for mobile number but I want mobile number should start with `7,8,9 digits`.I want to give validation that mobile number should start with `7,8,9 digits` only.

```
If Len(TextBox11.Text) < 10 Or Len(TextBox11.Text) > 10 Then
                MsgBox("Enter the phone number in 10 digits!", vbExclamation, "")
```

This code is gives `10 digits` validation but mobile number schould start with `7,8,9 digits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 digits, starting 7,8,9

```
isValid = TextBox11.Text like "[789]#########"

if (not isValid) then
    msgbox "Invalid"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Len(TextBox11.Text) <> 10 Or Left(TextBox11.Text, 1) <> "7" or Left(TextBox11.Text, 1) <> "8" or Left(TextBox11.Text, 1) <> "9" Then
                MsgBox("Enter the phone number in 10 digits!", vbExclamation, "")
End If
```

RegEx are a way for doing complex validation. It's in the VBScript library which is called Microsoft Regular Expressions 5.5.

```
[7-9]\d{9}$
```

a number between 7 and 9 `[7-9]`, followed by digits `\d` and there should be 9 of them `{9}`. `$` marks end of input so won't match if more than 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code which is work fine

```
Dim MobileNumber As New Regex("^[7-9][0-9]*")
                If MobileNumber.IsMatch(TextBox11.Text) Then
MsgBox("Valid Mobile number")
else
MsgBox("Not Valid Mobile number")
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Text7_LostFocus()
  Dim CHAR As Integer
  Dim TELEPHONE As String
  TELEPHONE = Val(Text7.Text)
  CHAR = Left(TELEPHONE, 1)
  If CHAR < 7 Then
    Msg("ENTR THE CORRECT  MOBILE NUMBER")
    Text7.Text
  Else If (TELEPHONE < 10) Then
    Msg("ENTR THE 10 DIGIT MOBILE NUMBER")
    Text7.Text
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -3):

```
Private Sub Text5_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
     If (Len(Text5.Text) < 10 Or Len(Text5.Text) > 10) Then
         MsgBox "Enter the phone number in 10 digits!", vbExclamation, ""
     End If
End Sub
```